# Problem with datasheet subforms using recursion to set control properties in form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am using a piece of code that successfully sets the background colour of controls on a form. And i use similar bits of code to set the background colour of required fields etc..

```
Public Sub colCtrlNorm(frm As Form)

Dim setColour As String
setColour = RGB(252, 252, 252)
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or         ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then
    ctl.BackColor = setColour
    ElseIf ctl.ControlType = acSubform Then
        colCtrlNorm frm(ctl.Name).Form
    End If
End With
Next ctl
Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Everything works fine and dandy except on a form that contains a subform which has nested datasheet.

When trapping the error I get the following error message:

```
Error 2455: You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Form/Report
```

I appreciate i cant change the datasheet controls background colour. This problem only arises with nested datasheets. Anyone any ideas as to how I can avoid this?

Thanks in advance for any assistance with this issue.

Cheers
Noel

Comment: I'm guessing here (I'd post an answer if I knew it was correct), but I think you should check to see if the parent of the subform control is in datasheet view, and skip it if so. A datasheet is a form, so a subdatasheet is a subform, but one that is the child of a form in datasheet view.

Comment: @David Yep, got it working by checking to see if the default view is as datasheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the parent of the subform control is in datasheet view, and skip it if so. A datasheet is a form, so a subdatasheet is a subform, but one that is the child of a form in datasheet view. Use the subform's .CurrentView property.

You can use the named constants that are part of the acCurrentView Enum:

```
  acCurViewDatasheet = 2
  acCurViewDesign = 0
  acCurViewFormBrowse = 1
  acCurViewPivotChart = 4
  acCurViewPivotTable = 3
  acCurViewPreview = 5
```

Obviously, some of those don't apply to forms but to reports, but they will still work.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

Got it working by using the following, which avoids subforms if there defauly view is datasheet (2)

```
Public Sub colCtrlNorm(frm As Form)

Dim setColour As String
setColour = RGB(252, 252, 252)
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Or ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Or         ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then
    ctl.BackColor = setColour
        ElseIf ctl.ControlType = acSubform Then
            If ctl.Form.DefaultView <> 2 Then
                colCtrlNorm frm(ctl.Name).Form
            End If
        End If
    End With
Next ctl
Set ctl = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you want to check CurrentView, not DefaultView, since the saved property can be overriden at runtime.